# Custom comment link

Tags: comments, comments-template

How can I customize my comment link without modifying `comment-template.php` file line 676:

```
$link = $link . '#comment-' . $comment->comment_ID;
```

I would like to get the same link just little modified and it should look like:

```
$link = $link . '?comments#comment-' . $comment->comment_ID;
```

And I'm using my comments to show like this:

```
$page = intval( get_query_var( 'cpage' ) );
if ( 0 == $page ) {
    $page = 1;
    set_query_var( 'cpage', $page );
    set_query_var( 'comments', '?' );
}

# We'll do 10 comments per page...
# Note that the 'page_comments' option in /wp-admin/options-discussion.php must be checked
$comments_per_page = 10;
$comments = get_comments( 
    array( 
        'status' => 'approve',
        'post_id' => $post -> ID,
    ) 
);

$args = array(
    'walker'            => null,
    'max_depth'         => '2',
    'style'             => 'ul',
    'type'              => 'all',
    'reply_text'        => 'Atsakyti',
    'page'              => $page,
    'per_page'          => $comments_per_page,
    'avatar_size'       => 0,
    'reverse_top_level' => null,
    'reverse_children'  => '',
    'format'            => 'xhtml', // or 'xhtml' if no 'HTML5' theme support
    'short_ping'        => false,   // @since 3.6
    'echo'              => true     // boolean, default is true
);

wp_list_comments( $args, $comments);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add your own custom `get_comment_link` filter just before you call the `wp_list_comments()` function:

```
// Modify comment links
add_filter( 'get_comment_link', 'wpse_comment_link', 10, 4 );

// Display comments
wp_list_comments( $args, $comments);
```

where our callback is defined as:

```
function wpse_comment_link( $link, $comment, $args, $cpage )
{ 
    // Only run it once
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // Modify the comment link
    return str_replace( '#comment-', '?comments#comment-', $link );
}
```

Hopefully you can adjust this to your needs.

Comment: yeah... it almost working.. just can't understand why it's missing 4 element `$cpage`... ?
if I turn it off no noticing, url is better.. but comment page after replying always first. :/

Comment: and I have some bad args in my dump
http://prntscr.com/98kyof
it's a last array of `$args` variable

Comment: but the args is bad only when I am posting a reply to comment, if i dump at my comments load then I see good args :)

Comment: how does the link look like when it fails? @Scorpioniz

Comment: /comment-page-1/?comments#comment-108 i.e. :) 
everythjing good with rewriting ?comments#comment-

just after replying an answer to parent comment it always returning to page 1..

Comment: and when the link is `/comment-page-1/?#comment-108` it works as expected? @Scorpioniz

Comment: yes.. almost :) but it's not your problem.. the link is correclty :) 
just i.e. if I replying to comment from comment-page-3 and after submiting form I am redirected to comment-page-1 (it should be 3) 
but still seems like I don't need comments with reply.. :/ 
but still very thankfull for  your answer! :)))

Comment: ok, I'm glad to hear you "almost" found a workaround ;-) @Scorpioniz